# 2-story house -- what would happen if I installed an AC unit in the window halfway up the stairs?

Tags: air-conditioning, stairs

I purchased a window AC unit without checking fit on all my windows. It won't fit my upstairs or downstairs windows. The only window it fits is halfway up the stairs.

[image: window halfway up stairwell]

Comment: Upstairs will probably stay warm/hot unless fans are added to push cool air up.  Cold sinks, warm rises.  Will probably not be happy with the purchase.

Comment: Set the exit fan louver/director to full up. Better than no AC, and depending on the fan in the unit it may well be able to overcome a certain degree of natural convection wanting to go the other way. Assuming, of course, you can actually reach an outlet to plug it into there.

Comment: Would probably make a good test question on HVAC test paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have a cool lower stairway. Any cool air from upstairs would be sucked into the unit and the colder air coming out would sink to the lower area. There's probably not an electrical outlet around there so you'd need an extension cord... very bad idea especially around/on stairs. the unit would be sticking out a bit and people using the stairs would be bumping into it. Return the unit or sell it on Ebay.

Comment: Or craigslist or facebook marketplace.

Comment: Thank you! Turns out I'm still in the return window so I got all but shipping back.